# Change properties of one table, but not for all tables

Tags: tables, formatting, scoping

How can I change properties (like `\arrayrulewidth` and `\arrayrulecolor`) of one table, but leave the other tables unchanged?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are the `tabular` (or `array`?) environments encased in `table` environments? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `\arrayrulecolor` inside of the `tabular` environment, the effect is local to this specific `tabular`. Other commands such as `\renewcommand{\arrayrulewidth}{...}` or `\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{...}` can be placed before the corresponding `tabular`. If both, the `tabular` and the before mentioned command are enclosed by  a set of `{}` (or a `table` environment), the effect will again be local to the specific `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline 
1 & 2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\arrayrulecolor{red} 
\hline 
3 & 4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline 
5 & 6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

{\renewcommand{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline 
7 & 8\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline 
9 & 10\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

{\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{20pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline 
11 & 12\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline 
13 & 14\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```